# How to get (int) values from POJO class object using JAVA generic

Tags: java, pojo

I have below piece of code which is going to get the value from given array list irrespective of data type. And It works fine.

```
   public static <E> void getAll(List<E> elements) 
    {
        for (E el : elements) 
        {
            System.out.println(el.toString());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception 
    {
        List<Integer> listInt = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        listInt.add(3);
        listInt.add(4);
        listInt.add(5);
        listInt.add(6);

        List<String> listStr = new ArrayList<String>();
        listStr.add("Animal");
        listStr.add("Ball");
        listStr.add("cat");
        listStr.add("dog");

        getAll(listInt);
        getAll(listStr);
    }
```

**Output:**

```
3
4
5
6

Animal
Ball
cat
dog
```

But I tried the same concept to get the data from POJO object but Its fail and return only object instead of Field as look like above.

The below code is my sample POJO:

```
  public class Test1 
  {

    private String car;
    private int price;

    public String getCar() 
    {
        return car;
    }

    public void setCar(String car) 
    {
        this.car = car;
    }

   public int getPrice() 
   {
    return price;
   }

   public void setPrice(int price) 
   {
    this.price = price;
   }
   public String toString() 
   {
    return String.format(car);
   }

  }
```

The below code is added into main() method:

```
     Test1 t1 = new Test1();
     t1.setCar("volvo");
     t1.setPrice(400000);

     Test1 t2 = new Test1();
     t2.setCar("datsun");
     t2.setPrice(500000);

     List<Test1> t1Array = new ArrayList<Test1>();
     t1Array.add(t1);
     t1Array.add(t2);

     getAll(t1Array);
```

And below is the output of the code:

**Output:**

```
 Volvo
 Datsun
```

Is there any other way to get the value (Integer) of the field, which will works for any type of POJO class.

Any leads?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. let me try that.

Comment: Test1 needs a toString method, which is what you call in getAll.

Answer (score 0):

Override the toString method in your POJO class:

```
public class Test1 
{
    public String toString(){
        return this.car;
    }
}
```